# consultas codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tengo un error en consultas con codeigniter, no se como eliminar esas comillas invertidas que se generan al pasar la variable $id2, y no me reconoce la variable $id2 como un numero.

```
function Consulta_iClientesall($id2)  
{   

         $this->db->select('timeZone.zone, clientes.iCliente,clientes.Telefono1, clientes.Telefono2 ');
              $this->db ->from('timeZone');
               $this->db->join('clientes',"clientes.iCliente= '$id2'" ,'inner');


               $this->db->where('SUBSTRING(clientes.Telefono1,1,4)= timeZone.areaCode ');
               $this->db->or_where('SUBSTRING(clientes.Telefono2,1,4)= timeZone.areaCode');
              //$this->db->get();
          return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

esto es el error que me devuelve

Error Number: 1064

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '` WHERE SUBSTRING(clientes.Telefono1,1,4)= timeZone.areaCode OR
>   SUBSTRING(clien' at line 3
>
> SELECT `timeZone`.`zone`, `clientes`.`iCliente`,
>   `clientes`.`Telefono1`, `clientes`.`Telefono2` FROM (`timeZone`) INNER
>   JOIN `clientes` ON `clientes`.`iCliente`= '`149'` WHERE
>   SUBSTRING(clientes.Telefono1,1,4)= timeZone.areaCode OR
>   SUBSTRING(clientes.Telefono2,1,4)= timeZone.areaCode

que sugieren?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba editando esta línea:

```
$this->db->join('clientes',"clientes.iCliente= '$id2'" ,'inner');
```

por esta

```
$this->db->join('clientes',"clientes.iCliente=" + $id2 ,'inner');
```

Comment: muchas gracias, si funciono.